$\frac{1}{|x-y|}$ is a tempered distribution in $\mathbb R^3$
I want to prove that $\frac{1}{|x-y|}$ is a tempered distribution in $\mathbb R^3$ where $y$ is fixed
I know that in $\mathbb R^3$  this function is $L_{1loc}$ so I can define the integral functional $\int\frac{1}{|x-y|}\varphi(x)dx=\langle G,\varphi \rangle$
my professor said this function defines a tempered distribution because  $\frac{1}{|x-y|}$  is slowly decreasing function (i e dominated by a polynomial $1+|x|^n$ so I can compute its Fourier transformation.
...This motivation  doesn't  convince me because in $x=y$ I have the explosion so how can I bound it with a polinomial ?
My ways of proving that a function defines a tempered distribution are

using definition $F\in D'$ is said to be tempered id it can be extended to a linear and continuous functional on $S(\mathbb R^n)$

if $f$ is in $L^p$

if the function is slowly  decreasing
...


I thought maybe to use definition 1 but linearity (if $\phi_k\rightarrow 0$  in $S$ then $\langle G ,\phi_k \rangle\rightarrow 0 $) stops me because I can't bring limit inside integral

You can because as you've written $\phi_k\rightarrow 0$ in $S$.

@Andrew   I think I have realized : I want to use dominated convergence so I have to estimate $\varphi_k \frac{1}{{x-y}}$ around the singularity i have that  \varphi_k is continuous so I can use sup to remove dependence of k   and around infinity I can use  $\varphi_k \rightarrow 0$ to say $\varphi_k  \frac{1}{{x-y}}<\frac{1}{x^(a+1)}$ and this is integrable . Is that right ?

Yes. And one can put $y=0$ for simplicity. Divide on two integrals, for $|x|\le1$ and $|x|>1$, dominated convergence works.

Just notice that
$$
\frac{1}{|x-y|} = \frac{1}{|x-y|} \,\mathbb{1}_{|x-y|\leq 1} + \frac{1}{|x-y|} \,\mathbb{1}_{|x-y|>1} \in L^1 + L^\infty.
$$

Of course it is, $x\in\Bbb R^3$
